# How to disable Nvidia AGX Xavier CPU cache?

Tags: nvidia, inline-assembly, ubuntu-18.04, arm64, cpu-cache

I would like to disable the CPU cache of the Nvidia AGX Xavier.

I've tried to use menuconfig to control the cache but it seems not working on this system. Then I tried to use ASM, and I got an error ' illegal instruction (core dumped )'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void L1_off(void){

    __asm__(
            "mrs x1, sctlr_el1;"        // read SCTLR_EL1
            "ldr x1, = 0xefff;"
            "and x11, x11, x1;"     // turn off bit 12 and store into R1 0xefff
            "msr sctlr_el1, x11;");     // restore R1 into SCTLR_EL1
                 }

 void L1_on(void){
     __asm__("mrs x11, sctlr_el1;"
             "ldr x2, = 0x1000;"
             "orr x11, x11, x2;"        // turn on bit 12 
             "msr sctlr_el1, x11;");
                 }

   int main(void){

        L1_off();
       //L1_on();   
       return 0;
                 }
```

Error message: illegal instruction (core dumped )

Comment: The `msr` and `mrs` instructions are privileged. Are you executing this in kernel mode or in user mode?

Comment: If this didn't just fault, you'd have another problem: Your unsafe inline-assembly clobbers registers without telling the compiler.  That will break whatever function this inlines into.  Or if any of those are call-preserved, will also break things even if it doesn't inline.  Note that `orr x11, x11, 0x1000` is encodeable: AArch64 immediates can use a pattern/shift encoding that can handle any single bit.  So you don't need to use 2 registers, only 1.  Use a dummy output operand to get the compiler to pick a tmp reg for you.

Comment: @fuz The instructions aren't technically privileged themselves, but the register OP is trying to access sure is.

Comment: A better way to write this code is `long reg; __asm__("mrs %0, sctlr_el1" : "=r"(reg)); /* set or clear bit here */ __asm__("msr sctlr_el1, %0" :: "r"(reg));`